# Closed caption not working in video webview Android

Tags: android, webview

I load URL by webview component, but the function closed-caption didn't work anymore. It works in the web browser but not work in webview. Any idea, solution for this case.
Already enable javascript, other functions work well except closed caption.
This URL example:
https://www.inquirer.com/video/remembering-chaney-a-2006-interview-with-john-chaney-reveals-his-philosophy-on-legacy-20210210.html

Answer (score 0):

After few day research I can resolve this issues. Add code bellow and it works.

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.766.0 Safari/534.36");
```

Comment: this doesn't work in my webview, is it still working for you?

Comment: @Troy, sory for reply too late but it still working on my side